# How to assign value in button and display the value at other activity?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, if-statement, switch-statement

I want to make the ImageView work as button, because I want it be able to click and go to another activity. Each imageView(button) should contain its own value. The problem is, I don't know how to pass the value in the imageView(button) to another activity. This is what I have tried so far:

```
public class ButtonClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View view) {

         String value = " "; 

        switch(view.getId())
          {
              case R.id.imageView2:
                                   value = "5";
                                   break;

             case R.id.imageView6: 
                                 value = "10";
                                  break;

             case R.id.imageView3: 
                                 value = "30";
                                  break; 

             case R.id.imageView02: 
                                 value = "50";
                                  break;  

             case R.id.imageView06: 
                                     value = "100";
                                     break;                



             default:
                                  break;
         }

        if(view.getId()==R.id.imageView2){

            //get the value from switch case and send to other activity

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public class ButtonClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View view) {
       switch (view.getId()) {
             case R.id.imageView2:
                  Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, YourOtherActivity.class);
                  intent.putExtra("YourKeyName", "5");
                  startActivity(intent);
                  break;
             case R.id.imageView6:
                  Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, YourOtherActivity.class);
                  intent.putExtra("YourKeyName", "10");
                  startActivity(intent);
                  break;
             case R.id.imageView3:
                  Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, YourOtherActivity.class);
                  intent.putExtra("YourKeyName", "30");
                  startActivity(intent);
                  break;
             case R.id.imageView02:
                  Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, YourOtherActivity.class);
                  intent.putExtra("YourKeyName", "50");
                  startActivity(intent);
                  break;
             case R.id.imageView06:
                  Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, YourOtherActivity.class);
                  intent.putExtra("YourKeyName", "100");
                  startActivity(intent);
                  break;
             default:
                  break;
        }
   }
};

 String valueFromIntent = getIntent().getStringExtra("YourKeyName");

 Intent intent = new Intent(YourSecondActivity.this, YourThirdActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("YourKeyName", valueFromIntent);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: actually I have four activity. When click at the imageView (in 1st activity), it will go to 2nd activity but the value from 1st activity will be used at activity 4th.. what confusing me now, is to get the value from 1st activity to be displayed at 4th activity :(

Comment: you can simply carry forword activity value to another activity.

Comment: sorry, I can't imaging how to do it..if refer to your code above it will straightly carry the value to the 2nd activity, right?

Comment: at 4th activity: 
    String valueFromIntent = getIntent().getStringExtra("YourKeyName");
   text2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
   text2.setText("Value: "+valueFromIntent);... I try to do this to display the value..but it become value= null

Comment: have you pass value from 3 to 4th activity as same above way.

Comment: I have checked...only when I press the back button, the 4th activity show the value.. :/

Answer (score 0):

Get the values from the Image view. Use Extras and send it to the other Activity.

Lets Say first Activity is X and Next Activity is Y :-

```
//Include this in your code in the first activity inside your if condition

if(view.getId()==R.id.imageView2){

        Intent main= new Intent(X.this, Y.class);
        main.putExtra("key", value);
        X.this.startActivity(main);
}
```

At Y Activity onCreate

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String value= intent.getStringExtra("key");
```

Hope it helps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("YourValueKey", value);
        startActivity(i);
```

here

```
 if(view.getId()==R.id.imageView2){

    //here

}
```

then you can get it from your second activity by :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String YourtransferredData = intent.getExtras().getString("YourValueKey");
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use Bundle to do the same in Android**

```
 //Create the intent
  Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
  AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete);
  String getrec=textView.getText().toString();

  //Create the bundle
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  //Add your data to bundle
  bundle.putString(“imagebuttonValue”, getrec);  
  //Add the bundle to the intent
  i.putExtras(bundle);

  //Fire that second activity
   startActivity(i);
```

**Now in your second activity retrieve your data from the bundle:**

```
//Get the bundle
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

//Extract the data…
String imagebuttonValue = bundle.getString(“imagebuttonValue”);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) you can call another activity and even send data with the help of `putExtra` from one activity to another activity, simply check below piece of code for understanding:

```
   Intent intent= new Intent(currentActivity.this,nextActivity.class);
   intent.putExtra("Key",yourvalue);
   startActivity(intent);
```

On next acitivty to retrieve data:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String yourvalue= intent.getExtras().getString("Key");
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass data trough `Intent` to your next activity and get your data in that activity like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this,SecondActity.class);
intent.putExtra("key",value);
startActivity(intent);
```

Get like this :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String value = intent.getStringExtra("key");
```

Answer (score 0):

u want to launch a new activity and pass the label value to that ?
if yes then just create an Intent and add the value to it , and use this intent to launch other acitivty.

for example if your value is "5" then :-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context) ;
intent.putExtra("key","5");
```

(refer [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29))

```
startActivity(intent);
```

and at `onCreate()` method of newly launched activity :-
`String value= getIntent.getStringExtra("key");` (Refer [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra%28java.lang.String%29) )